# Zapier Code (NodeJS) toLocaleString() timeZone

Tags: javascript, node.js, timezone, zapier

While attempting to utilize the code below:

```js
//Placed here for continuity sake
var inputData = {
    content: 'Created: 2018-03-06T13:58:35.660Z\nName: Operator\nText: test\n\nCreated: 2018-03-06T14:00:16.093Z\nName: Operator\nText: test'
    }
//Actual code in Zap
var transcript = inputData.content.replace(/(\d{4})(-(\d{2}))??(-(\d{2}))??(T(\d{2}):(\d{2})(:(\d{2}))??(\.(\d+))??(([\+\-]{1}\d{2}:\d{2})|Z)??)??$/gm,function(x){
                var dtin = new Date(Date.parse(x));
                var dtout = dtin.toLocaleString('en-US',{timeZone: "America/New_York",hour12: true});
                return dtout;
                })

//return {content : transcript}; commented in favor of console.log for here only
console.log(transcript);
```

The timezone portion of the conversion does not occur.  No errors are encountered when testing the step, it just doesn't convert to the EST timezone as it does everywhere else via the toLocaleString() function.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Works for me.  Even works here in the browser with the "Run code snippet" button (running Chrome).  Maybe you are on an older version of Node that doesn't have the Intl time zone support implemented?  What version of Node are you running?

Comment: Zapier uses Node 4.3.2, according to documentation.

Comment: Can you run `console.log(process.versions)` (in the real environment) and append to your question please?

Comment: Certainly, here it is:{ http_parser: '2.5.2',
node: '4.3.2',
v8: '4.5.103.35',
uv: '1.8.0',
zlib: '1.2.8',
ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
modules: '46',
openssl: '1.0.2k' }

Answer (score 0):

The `timeZone` parameter for `toLocaleString` is provided as part of the [ECMAScription Internationalization API](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-402.htm).  This is an optional API, in that one can build NodeJS *without* support for this.

From the output of `process.versions` you gave in comments, it would appear since there is no `icu` version reported, that indeed the instance of Node you're running on was built without internationalization support.  See [the NodeJS documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html) for further details.

Additionally, it's quite an old version of Node.  I'm not familiar with Zapier, but I see in [these Zapier docs](https://zapier.github.io/zapier-platform-cli/#how-do-i-manually-set-the-nodejs-version-to-run-my-app-with) that they allow you to use a newer version by updating the version of `zapier-platform-core` in your `package.json` file. You might want to set `>=3.10.10` and see if it picks up a newer Node version, perhaps one that has full Intl timeZone support.

Comment: That is what I expected.  Sadly that package.json option is for when I am developing my own app, not using the Zapier provided Code app.

I worked around this by hardcoding the timezone offset, which is fine since the end result is an email to only one timezone anyways.

Thanks for your help.